# UITableView in customCell hiding one button also hide the next button of other cells

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, uitableview

e.g as you are watching the tableView having cell with plus Button, when I press that button it hides the current button but when I scroll the tableview Some other button on other customCells are also get hide but I didn't hide them. please help me out. How to fit this problem.

[image]

Comment: What have you done to try to resolve this?  Also, please post the contents of your `-tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method.  Off the top of my head this sounds like it could be related to reuse of queued table cells.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i'll do it as follow:

first you have to track the button's state:
**Shown**
or
**Hidden**

this is done by holding the state in an **NSMutableArray**

in the `viewDidLoad` method add the following

```
NSMutableArray *shownButtons = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
```

then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath` do the following

```
NSString *tmpIndexPathString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",indexPath.row];
if ([shownButtons containsObject:tmpIndexPathString])
{
    [cell.myButton setHidden:YES];
}
else
{
    [cell.myButton setHidden:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The UITableView is caching the cells, which means it doesn't store all cells at all time, which is brilliant in terms of memory. The problem with it, that it has no reference to the value stored in that cell when the cell is reused. What is often done, is that all values stored in a dynamic cell is stored in separate NSMutableArrays.

For your problem, you could add an array with the boolean values indicating whether they are hidden or not, and read from that in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method with

```
cell.hidden = [[self.yourArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] boolValue];
```

And in the button callback method you should change the hiddenproperty as well as updating the value in the array.

Answer (score 0):

In the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method you need to loop through all the visible cells:

```
for (UITableViewCell *cell in [self.tableView visibleCells]) {
    // now you have a cell that you can update
}
```

You also have to remember to update your data source so scrolling the table will update the cells accordingly and not show the plus button. If you're updating your data source what you can do is reload the cell in the above for loop for example.